# Laravel JsValidator How to validate array input fields?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, jsvalidation

Suppose I have a field like

```
@for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
  <input type="hidden" name="my_field[$i]" value="$i"/>
@endFor
```

now how we can validate if `my_filed[]` array element has at least two value.
It means how to check if this array input field has two member?

Answer (score 0):

Use count:

```
$myField = Input::get('my_field');
if (count($myField) >= 2) {
    // $this->rollOutTransformers();
}
```

Comment: I think above code can be use after the form submit. How should we use that with `JsValidation`.